# How can i checkout only directory from SVN repositry in java

Tags: java, svn

I am new to SVN. I want to checkout all directories under the source folder of SVN repositry to my local, using java code.

I am using the below code but it is exporting both files and directories while I only want to copy the directories.

```
SVNClientManager ourClientManager = SVNClientManager.newInstance(null, authManager);
SVNUpdateClient updateClient = ourClientManager.getUpdateClient();
updateClient.setIgnoreExternals(false);
updateClient.doExport(url1, checkoutPath1, SVNRevision.create(111111), SVNRevision.create(111111),null,true,SVNDepth.INFINITY);
```

Comment: why don't you use tortoise SVN client to do that?

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct command to detch the dir from SVN.
You can you some code like below.

```
private List<String> dirCheckout(SvnOperationFactory svnOperationFactory) throws SVNException {
    SVNRepository repository = SVNRepositoryFactory.create(SVNURL.parseURIEncoded(URL),null);
    repository.setAuthenticationManager(svnOperationFactory.getAuthenticationManager());
    Collection<SVNDirEntry> entries = (Collection<SVNDirEntry>) repository.getDir("", (Your Object).getRevision(), null,(Collection<?>) null);    
    Iterator<SVNDirEntry> iterator =entries.iterator();
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    while(iterator.hasNext()){
        SVNDirEntry entry =(SVNDirEntry) iterator.next();
            if(entry.getKind()==SVNNodeKind.DIR)
                list.add(entry.getName());
        }
    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nohow.

It isn't possible (in single command) with existing `--depth` options in pure Subversion, I'm sure, SVNKit can't give more options than backend